# Knockout Model vs ViewModel

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js

I am trying to understand the difference between Model and ViewModel in KO. I understand the conceptual difference, but to me it seems that all Models in KO will become or are candidates to become ViewModels. Ill explain:

Say you have a table with a row of seats, so in your main **ViewModel** you will initialise and load a collection of objects from a Seat **Model** into an observable array.

Now you want to hide display seats based on a certain property of seats...this is the point where your model becomes another viewmodel...

So is it right to say that in KO all we have is ViewModels?

Comment: Not really. Your view model is responsible for setting values to the property e.g. isVisible for each object in your collection. So your view model also abstracts this collection. YOur model of a Seat only contains the definition for isVisible, it does not know what happens with it. And finally your data binding decides whether to show a seat or not in the UI based on the property value. That is a separation of concerns between the model and View model.

Comment: So you now saying the opposite, everyhting is a Model...so say here: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro AppViewModel is a Model and not a ViewModel...

Comment: What you have there is a very simplistic example. Usually a ViewModel data items are driven by what a view needs and it also has commands/functions to provide for interactions. A model does not handle interactions. I have extended that example a bit here to explain what I mentioned in my first comment. http://jsfiddle.net/UCmqk/1/

Comment: I understand the concept, but take your example and say you want to make a person visible on a grid or not, then you add an observable property to the person class. At this point your initial model is now driving the UI thus becoming a ViewModel.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. Essentially, anything with a `ko.observable` is creating a ViewModel. You could create a simple javascript model expressible as nothing but JSON, and wrap it, but the "model" in Knockout's MVVM pattern generally exists only on the *server*. You get the model data from the server, and you send model data back to the server (remember, you don't send the `observables`, just their data)

Knockout doesn't really care about where the model comes from, because its primary role is to deal with the databinding between the declarative view (HTML) and the ViewModel (with its View-aware `observables`).

The MVVM pattern is completed by technology outside of Knockout, since it's a client-side only framework. You could say that it is just the VVM part of the pattern, but that is confusing.

Comment: Yes, here's a quote from the KO Documentation: _When using KO, you will usually make Ajax calls to some server-side code to read and write this stored model data._ [KO Observables Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html)